# Is it possible to find a function $\theta(x,y)$ in terms of unknown $x(t), y(t) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ given $\theta' = yx' - xy'$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

The title basically states the problem:

Given $x(t), y(t) \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, is it possible to find an antiderivative $\theta(x,y)$ of
\begin{align*}
\theta' := yx' - xy'
\end{align*}
as an expression in terms of $x, y$? ($'$ meaning differentation w.r.t. to $t$.)

(The notation stems from the fact that the right hand side is indeed the derivative of an angle $\theta$, given $x = \sin(\theta)$ and $y = \cos(\theta)$. The question comes up in the context of the mathematical pendulum, which explains the unusual choice of $x$ and $y$ w.r.t. sine and cosine.)

I really don't know whether I should even expect a closed form solution for this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

**What I have tried:**

- I played around with integration by parts but only ended up with statements of the form x=x.
- Due to the similarity with the quotient rule I attempted to write $\theta' = y^2 \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)'$, but I know that $y$ may become zero, so this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: $x,y$ are functions of $\theta$? Because if they are we can write $\theta' := \cos \theta \cos \theta - \sin \theta (- \sin \theta) = 1 $

Comment: This is *heavily* context dependent. If (and this is not clear from your post) it is true that $x^2+y^2 = 1$, then we can say $$yx'-xy' = \frac{yx'-xy'}{x^2+y^2} = \left(\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)'$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know my trigonometry. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule, $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}x'(t)+\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}y'(t)$, but by assumption, this is $yx'-xy'$.  If you need this to hold for *every* choice of x and y, then that would force $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=y$ and $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}=-x$.  But if this were the case, calculating the second partial derivatives would yield $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\theta=-1$ while $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\theta =1$, which is impossible.

However, if you just need that this is true for one particular choice of $x, y$, then maybe.  As NinadMunshi showed in the comments, if $x^2+y^2=1$, then $yx'-xy' = \frac{yx'-xy'}{x^2+y^2} = \left(\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)'$. Or if $x$ and $y$ are both constant functions, then any theta works.  Or if $y(t)=c$ but $x$ is not assumed to be constant, then the equation simplifies to $\theta'=cx'$, and one can take $\theta=cx+d$. for any constant $d$.

I suspect that you can find such a $\theta$ for a given $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ if and only if the image of $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth curve (so that it never crosses itself, but it can trace back over itself like going around a circle multiple times), but I have not attempted to prove this.